# Axis2 - Unable to find a matching Operation for this remote invocation <xml-fragment>

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

Does anyone encounter this issue?

We have a web service that was developed using weblogic, I was able to successfully import the wsdl in soapUI and generate a client that was able to call the web service successfully. Then I was also able to generate a client jar for axis2 and include it in a project. But when I tried to call a web service in java code I got:

```
Unable to find a matching Operation for this remote invocation <xml-fragment>
```

Any idea what's causing the problem?

Thanks,

czetsuya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by using Axis1 inside soapUI. It seems our client is using an old technology.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem.

```
ListarRegionesDocument request = ListarRegionesDocument.Factory.newInstance();

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <xml-fragment/>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

SOLUTION

```
ListarRegionesDocument request = ListarRegionesDocument.Factory.newInstance();
//Add code
ListarRegiones lstRegion = ListarRegiones.Factory.newInstance();
request.setListarRegiones(lstRegion );

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <reg:listarRegiones xmlns:reg="http://region.webservices.col.direccionNormalizada.telefonica.cl/"/>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```